# Solution of the quasilinear equation $p - z q + z = 0$ with initial data curve

Tags: partial-differential-equations, curves, initial-value-problems

Hello ı cant write like maths notation hear sorry for that.
Find the solution of the initial value problem for the quasilinear equation
 $p - z q + z = 0$ for the initial data curve
$\Gamma: x_{0} = 0, y_{0} = s, z_{0} = -2s, −\infty \leq s \leq \infty $

I found $c_{1} = (e^x).z $
But ı dont know is it true or not and ı couldn't continue from this part. Can u help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$z_x-zz_y=-z$$
You correctly found a first characteristic equation :
$$ze^x=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation is :
$$z-y=c_2$$
The general solution is :
$$ze^x=F(z-y)\quad\implies\quad z=e^{-x}F(z-y)$$
Condition :
$$z(0,y)=-2y=e^0F(-2y-y)=F(-3y)$$
The function $F$ is determined :
$$F(X)=\frac23 X$$
We put in into the general solution where $X=z-y$
$$ze^x=\frac23 (z-y)$$
Solving for $z$ :
$$z(x,y)=\frac{-2y}{3e^x-2}$$